# ansible junos UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0:

Tags: ansible, junos-automation

I was trying to get ansible for Junos router. While I execute the following code I get the following error:

"An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start by"

I tired to enable netconf on end device but still no luck. I couldn't use any galaxy modules as we have that...

Am i missing something?

Thanks

```
  hosts: 10.1.1.1
  gather_facts: true
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - name: show version
      junos_command:
        commands:
          - show version
        host: "{{ ansible_host }}"
      register: output
```

Comment: which version of ansible you are using? Also, share debug logs when you run you playbook with debugging (-vvvv)

Answer (score 0):

UTF-8 bitstream cannot by specification contain 0xFE and 0xFF.

Answer (score 0):

UTF-8 bitstream cannot by specification contain 0xFE and 0xFF and you can find them using this command :

```
grep -P '[\xe9\xFF]' * -r
```